# What is a good approach to managing paypal-api credentials for a cloud-based build and deployment?

Tags: java, git, scala, paypal, cloudbees

I am trying to identify best practice for managing paypal-api credentials for a cloud-based build and deployment.

I have a scala app using the paypal java sdk. I have a sdk_config.properties containing my paypal api credentials. I don’t really want to leave those credentials lying around – I would like to integrate them into the app as late as possible. I manage my source via git.

I use a Jenkins job on cloudbees DEPLOY to build and deploy my app onto a cloudbees RUN instance.

Im wondering whether to use some kind of custom credential loader, or whether theres some way to manage that config file outside of the war.

I expect Im not the first person to ever want to do this so any pointers or suggestions to save me reinventing the wheel are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you should use RUN@cloud [configuration parameters](https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Configuration+Parameters). These are encrypted and can be accessed using system properties.

Comment: Externalize the properties and load them using a map instead of sdk_config.properties is the right answer here. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Not using sdk_config.properties makes it possible to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've ever found the BEST practice, but I can tell you how I've been handling this stuff myself.

In general, I have a config file of some sort (I typically work with php, so config.php).  This file contains all the credentials I might need for eBay, PayPal, social network sites, databases, etc.

On live servers, I put this file somewhere outside the web root so it's not publicly accessible.  Within the app I pull the config file in via absolute path.

In my Git repos I include a config-sample.php that has all of the placeholders ready to go with detailed comments and empty values.  If your live config file resides in the same place (for testing purposes) you could use .gitignore to ensure it never gets included with git actions.

That way anybody who ever forks my repo or wants to use the solution (if you're allowing that) has a sample of what the config file needs to include, and then I would provide a recommendation to place that outside the site root like I explained.  If you're not allowing people to use this thing like that then you may not even need to mess with a config sample.

I like to build my config files based on a SANDBOX flag that is either true/false.  I keep all my credentials for both sandbox and live servers in the config file, and the params are set based on the SANDBOX flag.  I also include a little chunk of code that checks the subdomain of the current URL and automatically sets the SANDBOX parameter for me.  That way anytime I'm running on sandbox.whatever.com it'll use sandbox credentials against sandbox servers, and anytime I'm running on www.whatever.com it'll use live credentials against live servers.

That way I never have to worry about remembering to update the credentials when I move from testing to live or visa-versa, which has bitten developers in the ass many, many times.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is exactly the kind of thing Im interested. Specificlly Im interested in doing something in a JVM environment where the deployment artificat is a single artifact. I like the sandbox flag idea.